# What is the recommended way of hosting In NServiceBus 6, self hosting or NServiceBus.Host.exe?

Tags: nservicebus

It seems NServiceBus is moving from configuration to Code. What are the additional benefits of hosting using NServiceBus.Host.exe vs hosting an endpoint yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what configuration via code has to do with hosting?

The NServiceBus Host offered features to make it easier to host your endpoints. Since then we have made a lot of this stuff easier or the features have been added to specific packages. So at the moment, it's as easy to host it yourself. And you'd have more control over setup, etc. For example the host has its own configuration and the endpoint itself as well. Some users have issues with assembly mappings that need to be in both places, etc.

So if you want to know how you can host yourself, there's documentation on that:

- [General hosting](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/)
- [Self hosting sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/self-hosting/)
- [Windows Service Hosting](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/windows-service)
- [Web Application Hosting](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/web-application)
- [Service Fabric Hosting](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/service-fabric-hosting/)
- [Shared Hosting in Azure](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/cloud-services-host/shared-hosting)

and much more on our documentation website.